# How to add a custom row for adding data to ember-table?

Tags: ember-cli, ember-table

I would like to add a custom row at the bottom of an ember-table so that it will allow the user to insert new rows to the table. Which approach should I take? The idea is similar to the one asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26601737/how-to-add-a-a-dynamic-row-to-table-on-click-of-a-button-and-make-the-existing) but using a fixed row and [ember-table](http://addepar.github.io/ember-table-addon/#/overview).

Comment: There are too many ways to approach this problem. The answers would just turn into a straw-poll for which one people liked. The best thing is to do some research on the topic yourself, find two or three, _analyze_ them, determine if they work for you or not, and _try them out_. Come to use when you have a specific question about something you have attempted to do.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @gunr2171 but I'm talking about something very specific, which is the add-on provided by Addepar  called ember-table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest extending Ember Table to override `footerContent`:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import TableComponent from 'ember-table/components/ember-table';
MyTable = TableComponent.extend({
  footerContent: ...
});
```

You'd then override `Ember.Table.Row` with a custom row, and put that into `footerContent`. You could define an extra action on that row which grabs the row's data and adds it to `content` backing the main table. (You'd need to pass a reference to `content` into your custom row).

You can do the same thing by overriding `bodyContent`, but I think using a footer is perfect for this purpose, and I increasingly think overriding `bodyContent` is a bad idea.

Comment: I'm not pretty sure how to override `Ember.table.Row`, is it like `financial-table-tree-row` in the financial table example?

Comment: Ok, I managed to show in the footer some info but how can I customize the row to show input fields instead of the actual cell-template?

Comment: @Henry, would you mind setting up an example in a JSBin? I'm needing to do the same thing, but I'm pretty new at Ember and not able to figure out all the code and plumbing that azirbel suggested. Thx.